# $USER var not set in VSCode's integrated shell

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code

When using terminal in Terminal the environment variable `$USER` is set to my user, however in VSCode's integrated shell it is not set at all.

`echo $USER` in Terminal:

```
bash-3.2$ echo $USER
aaron
```

`echo $USER` in VSCode integrated shell:

```
bash-3.2$ echo $USER
```

(empty line since it's not set)

From some looking around it seems that VSCode doesn't run as a "login shell" however even running `bash --login` VSCode integrated shell in the  doesn't solve this problem.

(Note: My operating system is OSX)

Comment: Have you set "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv" to false?